# Insert text into MS access cells

Tags: vb.net

i am begginer in visual basic and i want to insert text into cells in column in MS access but i doesn't find, how could i do that.
Here is code i tried:

```
     Private Sub UpdateDataBase2()

        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        datafile = "F:\Test Database\Database.accdb"
        conString = provider & datafile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = conString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into TABLA([LABELS]) Values (?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LABELS", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        Select Case panelCount
            Case 1
         '       TextBox1.Text = cmd.Add("LABELS").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString()
            Case 2
                ' str = "Insert into TABLA([LABELS]) Values (?)"
                'cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LABELS", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        End Select
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        myConnection.Close()

    End Sub
```

In this application, i made a dynamics panels and labels.(dynamics is for me generated in code)

panelcount is variable which saves to another MS acces database count of dynamics panels. I want to save text from labels to database systematically(it means: text from label 1 insert to cell 1.), but every code i tried was not function for me.

I know i have to use loop, but first i want to try if code works.
Sorry for my english.

Any solution?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are there errors?  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of records affected.  If it's more than zero, query worked.  `TextBox1.Text` is already a string.

Comment: No, it works but not how i want

Comment: We can't guess at the help you want.  It's not clear what you are asking your audience.

Comment: Sorry, if it doesn't clear. I want insert text into acces database but to specific cells. This code which i tried inserted text under itself.(in columns)

Comment: Try specifying the field (column) you want: `INSERT INTO [Labels] (columnA, columnB) VALUES (?, ?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database objects like `Connection` and `Command` should be declared in the method where they are used so they can be disposed.
Use `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Insert creates a new record. If you want to Update an existing record you will need the primary key value for the record you want to update.

```
Dim Str = Update TABLA Set [LABELS] = ? Where ID = ?
```

Then you will need a second parameter.

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = intID
```

You will need to declare and provide a value for intID.

Don't show a message box while a connection is open.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Try
        Dim Str = "Insert into TABLA([LABELS]) Values (?)"
        Dim ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Test Database\Database.accdb"
        Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("LABELS", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'Closes and disposes the connection and disposes the command
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. More people than you are.